# Anyone know what tumblr is written in

Tags: tumblr

Does anyone know what tumblr is written in? I have been trying to figure it out.

Comment: the webserver is Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)

Comment: @Ankit - That is a webserver... not a language

Comment: yup. I know thats y it is as a comment not answer!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's PHP...

http://www.marco.org/55384019

> [spiteshow](http://www.thespiteshow.com/post/55235440/phpframeworks):
>
> > I wonder if the Tumblr guys are using a framework or if it is all home brew.
>
> Both: it’s a homebrew framework to add MVC structure and a useful secondary function library to PHP 5 that we started in 2006 and have constantly evolved into a very finely tuned framework for our needs. The same framework runs some of Davidville’s former consulting-client sites as well as all of my personal sites and projects. It’s not available publicly anywhere, but we may release it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The [lead developer's blog](http://www.marco.org/) features a lot of PHP-related material, and Tumblr was advertising for PHP developers a while ago.  This isn't strong evidence, but it's possibly indicative and it's the best I could find.

Comment: Not necessarily.  All the URLs are probably being rewritten anyway.  They seem to have gone to reasonable effort hide the implementation language.  Also, if it wasn't PHP, why would they be hiring PHP engineers, and why would the lead developer have almost nothing about Ruby on his blog and lots on PHP?

Comment: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api  The code samples are all given in PHP, not in Ruby.  I'm pretty confident it's a PHP shop, probably in conjunction with some framework.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the full stack as of 2013.

"We're a LAMP based stack (Linux Apache MySQL PHP) with Scala for our many services. Other pieces of tech we use currently in production are Memcached, Varnish and Redis."

http://smcdermott.tumblr.com/post/46847264498/what-language-is-tumblr-written-in-all-php

Answer (score 0):

I just logged in to my account and added the index.php and it worked, so it must be php. 
http://www.tumblr.com/dashboard/index.php

Comment: What about: http://www.tumblr.com/register/index.asp
http://www.tumblr.com/register/index.asp http://www.tumblr.com/register/index.pl ???

Comment: I wouldn't say "trick"  it just looks for an existing action and if its not there, then go with the default. Its simpler than throwing 404's all over the place.