# How does tumblr handle subdomains?

Tags: .htaccess, webserver, server-side, tumblr

How does Tumblr handle account subdomains like *blogname*.tumblr.com? Is it an .htaccess redirect? If so, what code can I use to make something like that on my site?

Answer (score 1):

**Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) && PHP**, so it can be *.htaccess* redirects, but i think that is **serverside & database** redirects 'cause it is more flexible and fast solution than one big *.htaccess* file, which is locked every time you rewrite it with new data.

Related links:

- http://www.marco.org/2008/10/20/re-php-framework
- [Anyone know what tumblr is written in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326136/anyone-know-what-tumblr-is-written-in)